# Calculates and Generates student report card (Part 2)

Tags: c++, beginner, io

I've updated my code according to some tips from a previous post and would like to post the new code for review.

```
// Calculates and generates a report card of students final grades

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

float assignWeight;
float midtermWeight;
float finalWeight;
float participationWeight;

// Getting weight value for assignments
float assignmentWeight(){

    float weight;

    do{
        std::cout << "Enter the weighted value for the assignments in decimal form (Ex. 0.25): ";
        std::cin >> weight;
    }while(!(weight < 1 && weight > 0));

    return weight;

}

// Takes input and computes the average and returns a weighted score.
float assignmentScore(){

    float assignmentScore, average; 
    int numOfAssignments;
    int assignmentArray[11];
    int assignmentTotal = 0;

    std::cout << "Class Assignments: " << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Enter Number of Assignments MAX [10]: ";
    std::cin >> numOfAssignments;

    assignWeight = assignmentWeight();

    // getting assignment grades
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfAssignments; i++){

        do{
            std::cout << "Enter the score for assignment #" << i + 1 << "[0 - 100]: ";
            std::cin >> assignmentArray[i];
        } while(!(assignmentArray[i] >= 0 && assignmentArray[i] <= 100));
    }

    for( int j = 0; j < numOfAssignments; j++){
        assignmentTotal = assignmentTotal + assignmentArray[j];
    }

    // computes unweighted average
    average = float(assignmentTotal) / float(numOfAssignments);
    std::cout << "Average: " << average << std::endl;

    // computes weighted score 
    assignmentScore = average * assignWeight;
    std::cout << "Assignment Score is: " << assignmentScore << std::endl << std::endl;

    return assignmentScore;
}

// computes and returns weighted midterm score
float midtermScore(){

    float midterm, midtermScore;

    std::cout << "Midterm: " << std::endl;

    midtermWeight = assignmentWeight();

    std::cout << "Enter the score for the midterm: ";
    std::cin >> midterm;    

    midtermScore = midterm * midtermWeight;
    std::cout << "Midterm Score is: " << midtermScore << std::endl << std::endl;
    return midtermScore;
} 

// computes and returns the weighted final exam score
float finalScore(){

    float final, finalScore;

    std::cout << "Final Exam: " << std::endl;

    finalWeight = assignmentWeight();

    std::cout << "Enter the score for the final: ";
    std::cin >> final;

    finalScore = final * finalWeight;
    std::cout << "Final Score is: " << finalScore << std::endl << std::endl;

    return finalScore;

}

// computes and returns the weighted participation score
float participationScore(){

    float participation, participationScore;

    std::cout << "Participation Grade: " << std::endl;
    participationWeight = assignmentWeight();

    std::cout << "Enter Parcipation Score: ";
    std::cin >> participation;

    participationScore = participation * participationWeight;
    std::cout << "Participation Score: " << participationScore << std::endl << std::endl;

    return participationScore;
}

float bonusPoints(){
    char bonus;
    float bonusPoints;

    std::cout << "Would you like to enter any bonus points to be added to the final grade? [Y / N]" 
         << std::endl;
    std::cin >> bonus;

    if(bonus == 'Y' || bonus == 'y'){
        std::cout << "Enter number of points: ";
        std::cin >> bonusPoints;
    }else{
        bonusPoints = 0;
    }

    return bonusPoints;

}

std::string student(){
    std::string first_name, last_name, student;

    std::cout << "Students first name: ";
    std::cin >> first_name;

    std::cout << "Students last name: ";
    std::cin >> last_name;

    student = first_name + " " + last_name;

    return student;

}

std::string subject(){

    std::string classSubject,classProfessor, classInfo, classSemester, classYear;

    std::cout << "Enter the class Subject: "; 
    std::cin >> classSubject;

    std::cout << "Semester(Fall/Spring/Summer) and Year: ";
    std::cin >> classSemester >> classYear; 

    std::cout << "Professor: ";
    std::cin >> classProfessor;

    classInfo = "Subject: " + classSubject + "\n" 
              + "Semester: " + classSemester + " " + classYear + "\n" 
              + "Professor: " + classProfessor + "\n";
    std::cout << classInfo << std::endl;

    return classInfo;

}

int main(){

    float finalGrade, assignments, midterm, final, participation, weight, bonus;
    std::string name, classSubject;

    std::ofstream Grades;
    Grades.open("finalgrade.txt");

    std::cout << "Initializing Grading Program press [ctrl + Z] to quit: " << std::endl;
    name = student();
    classSubject = subject();
    assignments = assignmentScore();
    midterm = midtermScore();
    final = finalScore();
    participation = participationScore();
    bonus = bonusPoints();


    // Adds all scores together for final grade
    finalGrade = assignments + midterm + final + participation + bonus;
    std::cout << "Final Grade is: " << finalGrade << std::endl;

    // Check if there is a file to write to
    if (Grades.is_open()){
        Grades << std::string(40, '*') << std::endl << std::endl
               << "               2015 REPORT CARD                  " << std::endl
               << std::string(40, '*') << std::endl
               << std::endl;
        Grades << classSubject << std::endl;
        Grades << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
        Grades << "Assignment score out of " << assignWeight*100 << ":  " << assignments << std::endl;
        Grades << "Midterm score out of " << midtermWeight*100 <<  " :    " << midterm << std::endl;
        Grades << "Final Exam score out of " << finalWeight*100 << ":  " << final << std::endl;
        Grades << "Participation score out of " << participationWeight*100 << ":  " << participation << std::endl;
        Grades << "Bonus Points:                   " << bonus << std::endl;
        Grades << std::string(40, '*') << std::endl << std::endl;
        Grades << "The final grade is:            " << finalGrade << std::endl;

        if (finalGrade > 70){
            Grades << "Congratulations you passed!" << std::endl;
        } else {
            Grades << "You Failed, See you again next semester." << std::endl;
        }

        if (finalGrade > 90){
            Grades << std::string(20, '*') << std::endl 
                   << "    *           " << std::endl
                   << "   * *      *   " << std::endl
                   << "  * * *   ***** " << std::endl
                   << " *     *    *   " << std::endl 
                   << std::string(20, '*') << std::endl << std::endl;
        }

    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Could not write to file because it failed to open" << std::endl;
    }

    Grades.close();

    return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should have each function do one thing, and have it do what it says.  In your `subject()` function, you get info for the entire class, and you also print it out, which prevents you from just getting the info and doing what you want with it without printing data out.  Given the name, this function should only be getting the class subject.

Second, you have `main()` doing way to much.  `main()` should only be used as the entry point to the program, and it should delegate the work to other functions.

Third, this looks like a good place to bring C++'s OOP into play.  Why don't you look into making a `class` for the class' data, professor, students, etc.?  You could also make a `class` for the students and keep a list of all the students in the class.

Finally, you still have the magic constant `100` in your code: `participationWeight*100`.  That should be a named constant variable in your code.  Additionally, your code will be easier to read if you use spaces around your operators.